# Having Issues Checking Workstation Bitlocker Status Remotely

Tags: powershell, bitlocker

I've created a ps1 file that runs on our UTIL server for all workstations on our domain that checks if the computer is online, skips offline computers, checks bitlocker status, formats results, and writes to a CSV file.

The script essentially uses manage-bde -cn $Computer -status C: and works great on most machines. However, there are a few machines that are confirmed on the network and online that do not reply with the status.

I ran the same command manually in powershell on the UTIL server to the affected machines and get the result "ERROR: An error occurred while connecting to the Bitlocker management interface. Check that you have administrative rights on the computer and the computer name is correct" If I connect to the computer and check status on the computer itself, it displays results no problem.

I'm logged into the UTIL server as an admin running powershell as admin. My question is, what would cause some computers to return results successfully and others to have an issue connecting to the Bitlocker management interface? Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

What process is executing your script when you're not in an interactive session? A scheduled task, a service? What security context does that process run in?

Based on some other threads I have seen on this, you should check these items:

1. Not running the command as an admin
2. Not having a compatible TPM
3. The TPM being disabled in the BIOS (it is on many computers)
4. The TPM or BitLocker services not being started.
5. A TPM reporting as a 1.2 TPM when in fact it is a 1.1 TPM.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my net.
Solved by setting up one rule for remote client Windows firewall. Ther rule is intended to allow WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) access to Remote Machine (see this link for further info https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/a2f2abb3-35f6-4c1a-beee-d09f311b4507/group-policy-to-allow-wmi-access-to-remote-machine?forum=winservergen ) 
Regards

Andrea